# Getting LocalDate to display in a Tableview in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, localdate

I have been working on part of my application that allows a user to input holidays that their school takes off and saves it to a file. The name of the holiday and the date (stored as a LocalDate object) is read from the file and stored in a holiday object and put into an observable arraylist.

This is the main controller:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Optional;


public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private BorderPane mainGridPane;
    private ArrayList<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
    private static XSSFRow row;
    private boolean fileClosed = false;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker employeeStartDate;
    @FXML
    private Label evaluation40;
    @FXML
    private Label evaluation80;
    @FXML
    private Label evaluation120;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker summerStart;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker summerEnd;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker fallStart;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker fallEnd;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Holiday> tableView;

    private HolidayData data;

    public void initialize() throws IOException {
        data = new HolidayData();
        data.loadHolidays();
        tableView.setItems(data.getHolidays());

    }
```

This is the Holiday Class:

```
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Holiday {
    private SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> date;


    public Holiday(String name, LocalDate date) {
        this.name.set(name);
        this.date = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(date);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateProperty() {
        return date;
    }
```

This is the HolidayData class that is responsible for reading the data to and from files and producing and observable arraylist:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class HolidayData {
     private static HolidayData instance = new HolidayData();
     private static String fileName = "schoolHolidays.txt";
     private DateTimeFormatter formatter;

     private ObservableList<Holiday> holidays;

     public HolidayData(){
         formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
     }

    public static HolidayData getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public ObservableList<Holiday> getHolidays(){
         return holidays;
    }

    public void addHoliday(Holiday holiday){
         holidays.add(holiday);
    }


    public void loadHolidays() throws IOException {
        holidays = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path);

        String input;
        try{
            while((input = br.readLine()) != null){
                String[] holidayPieces = input.split("\t");

                String name = holidayPieces[0];
                String dateString =  holidayPieces[1];

                LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);
                Holiday holiday = new Holiday(name, date);
                holidays.add(holiday);
            }
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            if(br != null){
                br.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void storeHolidays()throws IOException{
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(path);
        try {
            Iterator<Holiday> iter = holidays.iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Holiday holiday = iter.next();
                bw.write(String.format("%s\t%s", holiday.getName(), holiday.getDate().format(formatter)));
                bw.newLine();
            }
        }finally {
            if (bw != null){
                bw.close();
            }

        }
    }

    public void deleteHoliday(Holiday holiday){
        holidays.remove(holiday);
    }
}
```

This is the tableView portion of the FXML file:

```xml
<TableView fx:id="tableView">
    <columnResizePolicy>
        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY"/>
    </columnResizePolicy>
    <columns>
        <TableColumn text="Holiday Name">
            <cellFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="name"/>
            </cellFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn text="Date">
            <cellFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="date" />
            </cellFactory>
        </TableColumn>
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

The problem I am running into is `java.lang.ClassCastException` saying the table column cannot be cast to a certain object, which I think is the `LocalDate` object. I am using the SimpleObjectProperty to databind it to the FXML file, but I can't seem to get it to work. The only other thing I can think to do is just make the date in `Holiday` a `SimpleStringProperty` and convert that to a `LocalDate` in all the other parts in my code, but that seems unnecessary. I appreciate any insight anyone can give me.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR version: you are confusing the `cellValueFactory` with the `cellFactory`. See, for example, [this tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-cell-renderer/) for a nice explanation of the difference, which is summarized for this particular example below.

A table column's `cellValueFactory` is an object that tells the column *which* values to display in the cells, or more precisely how to get those values from the objects representing each row. This is represented by a `Callback<CellDataFeatures<Holiday, LocalDate>, ObservableProperty<LocalDate>>`, i.e. a function mapping a `CellDataFeatures<Holiday, LocalDate>` to an `ObservableValue<LocalDate>`. So in Java code you would do

```
dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(holidayRowData -> holidayRowData.getValue().dateProperty());
```

or, if you prefer to use the (somewhat legacy) `PropertyValueFactory` class, you can do

```
dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));
```

The latter version has the (many disadvantages, but the one) advantage that it can be done in FXML as well. Note, though, that you want the `cellValueFactory`, not the `cellFactory`. So your FXML should be

```xml
<TableView fx:id="tableView">
    <columnResizePolicy>
        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY"/>
    </columnResizePolicy>
    <columns>
        <TableColumn text="Holiday Name">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="name"/>
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn text="Date">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="date" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

The `cellFactory`, by contrast, is an object that tells the column *how* to display the data. It is represented by a `Callback<TableColumn<Holiday, LocalDate>, TableCell<Holiday, LocalDate>>`, i.e a function mapping a `TableColumn<Holiday, LocalDate>` to a `TableCell<Holiday, LocalDate>`. The `ClassCastException` occurs because the cell factory you set is going to be passed the `TableColumn`, but is expecting to receive a `CellDataFeatures`, and so when it tries to treat it as such, the cast fails.

You may well want a cell factory here, in addition to the cell value factory, so that you can control *how* the date is displayed (e.g. control the format used for it). If you give the date column an `fx:id`, say `<TableColumn fx:id="dateColumn">`, and inject it into the controller with

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Holiday, LocalDate> dateColumn ;
```

then in the controller's initialize method, you can do:

```
public void initialize() throws IOException {
    data = new HolidayData();
    data.loadHolidays();
    tableView.setItems(data.getHolidays());

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    dateColumn.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<Holiday, LocalDate>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(date, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText("");
            } else {
                setText(formatter.format(date));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed it. Your explanation made it a lot clearer.